# no matching function to call 'strlen'

Tags: c++

I'm trying to allocate memory for my pointer char array
but I keep getting no matching function to call 'strlen'

```
int ItemList::getItemNames(char ** & itemNames) const{
  int counter = 0;
  int MAX_NAME = 50;
  char buffer[MAX_NAME];
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    int length = strlen(list[i].getItemName(buffer));//ERORR
    itemNames[i] = new char[length + 1];
    counter++;
  }
  
 
  return counter;
}
```

this is the getItemName()

```
void InventoryItem::getItemName(char returnName[]) const
{
    strcpy(returnName, itemName);
}
```

Comment: Well, whatever that mysterious `getItemName()` method returns, it cannot be converted to a `const char *`, which is what `strlen()` requires. Without a [mre] it's not possible to tell you anything else.

Comment: Ok, yes, `getItemName()` returns a `void`. How did you expect to pass a `void` to `strlen()`? C++ does not work this way. You need to call it independently, then when it returns pass `buffer` to `strlen()`. Additionally, using C-style string handling libraries and plain `char` buffers results in fragile code that's vulnerable to buffer overflow, leading to hard to diagnose bugs. We can do better in C++. We can use `std::string`, iterators, and algorithms to make it logically impossible for these kinds of bugs to occur.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getItemName` doesn't return anything (`void` as a return type means a function returns nothing). It modifies its argument. So you need to pass the `buffer` argument to `strlen`.

```
list[i].getItemName(buffer);
int length = strlen(buffer);
```

Comment: Silly me.. 
thank you so much!